Why sub package cannot find dependencies when use alias in parent TS project?
I have an older Lerna TypeScript project that contains several packages. I recently added a package called 'kc-vue', which is a Vue wrapper for the latest Keycloak-JS. The latest Keycloak-JS requires moduleResolution: bundler, while the other packages use moduleResolution: node.
Additionally, I have another parent TypeScript Vue project that I use to debug the Lerna packages. This parent project also uses moduleResolution: node.
To facilitate debugging, I configured the following alias (where 'design-system' refers to the root directory of the Lerna project):
chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.resolve.alias
      .set('@', resolve('src'))
      .set('assets', resolve('src/assets'))
      .set('components', resolve('src/components'))
      .set('public', resolve('public'))
      .set(
        '@xxx/common',
        resolve('design-system', 'packages', 'common', 'src', 'public-api.ts'),
      )
      .set('@xxx/kc-vue', resolve('design-system', 'packages','kc-vue', 'src', 'public-api.ts'))

When I start the parent project, it will always throw info like:
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                                                                                                                        17:49:32

This dependency was not found:

* keycloak-js in ./design-system/packages/kc-vue/src/public-api.ts

Actually the keycloak-js is correctly imported in the kc-vue project, and the kc-vue project is tested successfully in a separated vue2 project.
I haven't any clue why it will throw this error when start the parent project.
